# Cache-Control private in kiosk mode

Tags: security, http, authentication, caching, browser

Suppose I expose a REST service (over HTTPS) that uses bearer token authentication (JWT) and responds to a GET request with the `Cache-Control: private` header.

Now suppose my application is used in kiosk mode (multiple users use same browser session as same OS user, think internet cafe or something). User1 makes an authenticated request to a resource.

```
GET /api/resource
Authorization: bearer <token1>
```

The response starts with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
```

Now, User1 signs out of my application and User2 signs in. The browser makes a request to the same resource on her behalf (but with a different JWT token).

```
GET /api/resource
Authorization: bearer <token2>
```

Now my question is, would the browser consider serving this from cache as it's the same request from the same OS user? Or would the browser consider the `Authorization` value in that decision?

If the former, would a `Vary: Authorization` header in the original response change that behavior.

Comment: Note that unless you set `Cache-Control: no-store`, private information from users' session will remain on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [RFC 2616, Section 14.9.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1), the `Cache-Control: private` response header will indeed mean that your multiple kiosk users, sharing the same browser session, will all get the same cached response.

And yes, adding a `Vary: Authorization` response header would help, as indicated by [Section 13.6](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.6) of RFC 2616; it tells the cache to keep/select from among different "representations" of the resource, based on the request headers listed in the `Vary` response header value.

Hope this helps!